# PostgreSQL: Permission denied + has wrong ownership loop?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run postgresql on my local machine like I usually do, however it's putting me in a situation where I can't fix. I installed postgresql91 with macports.

These are the three commands I usually have to run to get it running:

```
    sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=4096
    sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
    sudo su postgres -c "/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb -p 55432"
```

However, it's giving me this error today:

```
    Nets-Mac-Pro:~ emai$ sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=4096
    Password:
    kern.sysv.shmall: 4096 -> 4096
    Nets-Mac-Pro:~ emai$ sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
    kern.sysv.shmmax: 16777216 -> 16777216
    Nets-Mac-Pro:~ emai$ sudo su postgres -c "/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb -p 55432"
    postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

When I go to `/opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/` and do an `ls -l` this is what comes up:

```
drwx------  18 root  wheel  612 Jun 28 12:44 defaultdb
```

So I decided to add the postgres user to the wheel group, and then chmod defaultdb to 770.

```
drwxrwx---  18 root  wheel  612 Jun 28 12:44 defaultdb
```

I still get the error:

```
FATAL:  could not open configuration file "/opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

And so I change the file rights from:

```
-rw-------   1 root  wheel  19170 Jan  7 11:52 postgresql.conf
```

to:

```
-rw-rw----   1 root  wheel  19170 Jan  7 11:52 postgresql.conf
```

And now it complains that when I run the command again:

```
    Nets-Mac-Pro:~ emai$ sudo su postgres -c "/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb -p 55432"
    FATAL:  data directory "/opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb" has wrong ownership
    HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

I have no clue how I used to run the postgres server considering the file permissions of the files. Where do I find the `data` folder that it is hinting me about? Is there a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres should be owner, and the only user capable of writing to, data directory.

So, do:

```
sudo chown -Rf postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb
sudo chmod 700 /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb
```

and it should be fine.

Comment: did that worked?, im using `/usr/local/pgsql` folder. it is giving permission error, saying cannot access the `postgresql.conf` file. suggest me